# Trying to resize an UIView when text in a label is hidden

Tags: swift, uiview

```html
@IBOutlet weak var CompanyDetailsBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var CompanyDetailsView: UIView!
    @IBAction func toggleCollapisbleView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if(CompanyDetailsView.isHidden){
            var _CompanyHeight: CGFloat {
                get {
                   return CompanyDetailsBottom.constant.magnitude
                }
                set {
                    CompanyDetailsBottom.constant.magnitude = 0
                }
            }
            CompanyDetailsView.isHidden = false
        }else {
            CompanyDetailsView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    
}
```

I am trying to resize a view if the label is hidden, I get Cannot assign to property: 'magnitude' is a get-only property as an error.

Comment: Hi Daniel, it would help others answer your question if you format the code snippet more clearly. There seems to be a stray `}` at the end and the first line has less indentation than the others, which makes it look like the rest is part of the first declaration. I am not familiar with `NSLayoutConstraint` but did you try just running `CompanyDetailsBottom.constant.magnitude = 0` directly instead of putting it inside the setter of a computed variable like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, if you don't want to use constraints is to embed your `CompanyDetailsView` inside a vertical `UIStackView` and then when you hide it, the height of the stack view will automatically be 0.

Is the `UILabel` embed in the `UIView` ? If so you could change the `UIView` to be a `UIStackView` instead so the height will be 0 if the label is hidden

Comment: Embedding it in the UIStackView worked brilliantly! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension below to hide a view and its parent will adjust its height

```
extension UIView {

    var isGone: Bool {
        get {
            return isHidden
        }
        set {
            let constraints = self.constraints.filter({ $0.firstAttribute == .height && $0.constant == 0 && $0.secondItem == nil && ($0.firstItem as? UIView) == self })
            self.isHidden = newValue

            if newValue {
                if let constraint = constraints.first {
                    constraint.isActive = true
                } else {
                    let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                    // constraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
                    self.addConstraint(constraint)
                    constraint.isActive = true
                }
                self.setNeedsLayout()
                self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            } else {
                constraints.first?.isActive = false
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And all the constraint priorities of the child views must be less than 1000 (999 max)

Using:

```
childView.isGone = true
```